# Como adicionar valor a variável em jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

- Tenho uma variável `x` que está escrita na tela com valor inicial 0;
- Quero que a cada clique em um botão (seja `input` ou `button` mesmo) no arquivo HTML, o valor dessa variável seja acrescido 1;
- Ao ser acrescido, quero que a variável, que está escrita na tela, mostre o valor atual da mesma.

Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
var pontos = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pontos').text('Olá! O seu recorde é de ' + pontos + ' pontos.');

    $('#addPonto').click(function() {
        pontos++;
    });
});
```

Ao fazer isso, quero que o valor escrito na tela seja atualizado. Como proceder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O teu código está certo, só falta o passo onde escreves na página, ou seja mudas o texto que está em `#pontos` usando novamente a linha que já tens mas dentro da função que é corrida a cada clique.

Pode também colocar esse elemento `#pontos` em cache para não teres de ir buscar com jQuery a cada clique. Deixo uma sugestão, que usa menos jQuery:

```
var pontos = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divPontos = document.getElementById('pontos');
    divPontos.innerHTML = 'Olá! O seu recorde é de ' + pontos + ' pontos.'
    $('#addPonto').click(function () {
        pontos++;
        divPontos.innerHTML = 'Olá! O seu recorde é de ' + pontos + ' pontos.'
    });
});
```

#### exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/jw087L4u/

Comment: Muito obrigado, Sergio. Fiquei um tempo sem acesso a internet, por isso a demora.

Answer (score 2):

No caso, para atualizar o valor, voce teria que reescrever a atualização do campo, dentro da ação do clique do botão, dessa maneira:

```
var pontos = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pontos').text('Olá! O seu recorde é de ' + pontos + ' pontos.');

     $('#addPonto').click(function() {
            pontos++;
            $('#pontos').html('Olá! O seu recorde é de ' + pontos + ' pontos.');
    });
});
```

Dessa maneira a modificação do campo fica ligada ao click do botão.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo!

Comment: @GabrielAzevedo lembrando que sempre é bom marcar a pergunta como respondida se a resposta resolveu seu problema...